# SVN - Creating New Users (Access)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I`ve just created new user in Tortoise SVN. When I configure  the repository in their machine, the following warning message appears: "Target Folder is Not Empty. Are you sure you want to checkout/export into that folder?" (Message attached).

I'm just afraid of clicking in "Yes - Checkout into the non empty folder" and all the files from the original repository move to the new address.

Actually, I just want to give them access to the original repository and not move the files from the original path to a new one.
Anyone knows what will happen if I click "Yes"? Other users will lose access?

Comment: What do you mean by "configuring the repository in their machine" ?

Comment: You cannot "create a new user in TortoiseSVN". TortoiseSVN is a client application, not a server. Therefore, the question is unclear.